# Paginated REST response ingestion to JPA

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am getting a long list of items from a REST api, and it looks like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "foo1": "bar1" },
        { "foo2": "bar2" },            
        ...
        { "foo100": "bar100" },            
    ],
    "paging": [
        "total": 50000,
        "current": 0,
        "offset": 100
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to automatically map each item to an Item entity and store it to the persistent layer, but also to iterate through the pages to ingest all objects in one go?

Many thanks, 
VG

Answer (score 0):

### Yes ...

There is a `PagingAndSortingRepository` that works with non-native-only-queries. You can use `Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);` having informations about the current page in `pageable` and you can use it for direct JSON-serialization ....

### ... but ...

RESTful does by specification not allow that! REST means Representational so the url is like `/user/4145` so the response Represents the user having the ID 4145.

This means

1. No data needs pagination, if you need the posts he wrote you will write `/user/4145/post` to get a list (89234, ...) of post-ids and `/user/4145/post/89234` to get informations about one post.
2. `total`, `current`, `offset` is not *representational* for the user.